# How can I turn off all formatting symbol and dots inside Flash IDE?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

In my flash IDE, somehow I hit a hot key and turned on all the formatting symbols (paragraphs and dots). I cannot figure out how to turn them off, can anyone help me?
I search the web and SO without any results.

[Here is a picture](http://www.screencast.com/users/jdecuyper/folders/Jing/media/2867ab0d-7ccb-4f97-827a-248d5afa7732) of what is happening. ¿Any clue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Flash CS3 and CS4, go View -> Hidden Characters
The short cut is Ctrl+Shift+8

Comment: ohh thanks a lot,this is hide all paragraph marks on action script panel